# Creating an array dynamically and inserting in MySQL DB through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to create an array which will be passed to the insert query like this:

```
$data=array(
'db_field1'=>$value,
'db_field1'=>$value,
'db_field1'=>$value,
and so on
);    
$this->db->insert('table',$data)      //codeigniter syntax
```

But I want to create the array in advance and then keep on passing it key value pairs whenerver a condition is matched:

```
if(cond==true)
'"'.$key.'"=>'.$value.',' //pass this to the data array every time the condtion is true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$data['db_field1'] = $value;
if(cond==true){
$data[$key] = $value;
}
```

and so on........

Then run insert

```
$this->db->insert('table',$data);
```